# How can I check if a controller was called using post or get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

In ASP.Net MVC, how can I check in a controller method, if it was called using post or get?

I am aware I can limit methods to being called only by post or by get - but how can I check for post/get in a method that allows both?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod
```

or just

```
Request.HttpMethod
```

in Controller

Comment: Just be aware that if you're using this to force an action method to only accept a particular method, you can instead use the `[HttpPost]` or `[HttpGet]` attribute, which is clearer, more succinct, and more reliable (this will cause a server error when using the wrong method, something like "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request".)

Answer (score 11):

You can check the [Request.HttpMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

I use this combination for checking in view also

```
var method = Request.HttpMethod;

if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST") {
    var check = "";
}

if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET") {
    var check = "";
}
```